# SwiftUI HTTP Post Request

Tags: http, request, swiftui

**JSONService**

During the http request process, completion nil is returned. completion does not work.. but print function is working. how can i fix this problem. I am using http request for the first time. my English is bad. I'm sorry for that.

```
class JSONService {
    
    let parameters = ["index": "articles"]
    
    func getNews(completion: @escaping (NewsRoot) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://yazar.io/api/v2/search/") else { return }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
            
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else { return }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let news = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsRoot.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(news) //does not work
                    print(news) //works
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**DataStore**

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var news: [News] = []
    
    init() {
        getNews()
    }
    
    func getNews() {
        JSONService().getNews { (news) in
            self.news = news.articles
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
 @ObservedObject var news = DataStore()
```

Comment: Most probably your `DataStore` object got destroyed till that time. Set breakpoint into `init` and `deinit` and see how many times do you get into there.

Comment: deinit does not work. init is running.